# Bottom panel disappears when a new message arrives on Empathy in Gnome Shell Remix 12.10

Tags: 12.10, panel, empathy, system-tray

Every time a contact sends a message (just when its window is closed), the bottom panel with message tray disappears. I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and "r" and back to normal. Why it's happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug. See [this launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1067265) for the report.

AFAIK, it hasn't been fixed yet.